# Why I don't need memory barriers when starting drawing on an acquired swapchain image?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm learning Vulkan and my experience with memory barriers was quite good until I have to deal with memory visibility.

I feel like I have to use a memory barrier each time I start using a ressource for reading when I was previously writing on it, and inversly. A bit like if there was a state on the memory which says if it's used for writing or for reading. I know that the rationals for this are related to cache management, but at a higher level that's how I see it.

Bad things start when I don't see memory barriers, where according to my (very likely wrong) understanding they should be.

For example, if I want to draw something and present it on the screen, there is no memory barrier to make a transition from a swapchain image used for presentation (and thus for reading) to an image used for drawing (and thus for writing). And when I finish drawing, there is no barrier in the reverse order aswell.

I have seen the same thing happen when copying a staging host visible buffer to a device local buffer. You write something in the mapped memory, flush it, and then start recording the copy in a command buffer without putting any barrier to transition from a host writable memory to transfer read memory. So I'd like to know what I misunderstand or what implicits things make everything work out of the box.

Comment: "*there is no memory barrier to make a transition from a swapchain image used for presentation (and thus for reading) to an image used for drawing (and thus for writing)*" ... what do you mean by that? Swapchain images have to undergo a layout transition before they can be attached to a framebuffer. So are you talking about the behavior of *correct Vulkan code*, or Vulkan code you've seen/written that happens to get away with some stuff?

Comment: I can't say if it's correct or not, but it's working well. This tutorial for exemple https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Command_buffers

Comment: You need barriers in all those cases, and layout transitions in some. Without the barriers, you have race conditions. As with race conditions between threads on the CPU, many times you'll just "get lucky" and the ordering you want will just happen to be what you get. On some implementations, implementation details might make that happen reliably even. But a change to the driver, or running on a different GPU .. and suddenly you'll start seeing corruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No barrier between presentation is illegal. The swapchain image must be in `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR` for presentation. And it must be in different layout when your app does write something to the image. Only way to achieve this is with barrier-like primitive.

Writes to mapped memory is one rare exception. Writes to mapped memory are automatically visible to any subsequent `vkQueueSubmit`. See [Host Write Ordering Guarantees](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-submission-host-writes) chapter of the specification.

Why the tutorial does not have barriers there is because it covers synchronization in the [next chapter](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Rendering_and_presentation) you assumably did not reach. They do so with Subpass Dependencies. The layout transitions that are part of that are shown in [earlier chapter about render passes](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Render_passes).

Comment: So there is no kind of "state" to which transition memory when it has been completely written back. The VkAccessFlags are only used to make the memory available as soon as possible when synchronizing accesses. Is that right ?

Comment: @Nowine I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Let's say that you have 3 buffers A,B and C. I want to copy A to B, and then B to C, and to manage synchronization, I use a very coarse vkDeviceWaitIdle() function between the copies (performance are not important here). I do not need to put a memory barrier _after_  the vkDeviceWaitIdle() call to transition the buffer B from VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT to VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT right ? That's what I mean by a "memory state".

Comment: The 3 buffers are device local, and the two copies are recorded in a different command buffer. So you submit the first one, wait, submit the second one. This way, the barrier that I'm talking about would be in the second one.

Comment: No, but you need to change the image layout anyway, unless you are using `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL`.